Should mastercoin be renamed to omni or omnilayer?
There is currently a mastercoin tag. However, mastercoin renamed to Omni quite some time ago, and is no longer used. Most users who started in recent times simply know it as Omni or Omni Layer. 
I suggest that we merge the mastercoin and omni tags in light of this.

Looks like you're right

Thanks! I've 

merged mastercoin into omni 
kept mastercoin as a synonym for omni,
added omnilayer as a synonym for omni,
and added a brief description to the tag:   


Omni is a second layer protocol on top of Bitcoin that uses
  OP_RETURN outputs to track payments. Omni was previously called
  Mastercoin.



Thank you! Might also be worthwhile to create an omnilayer synonym. I tried, but I don't have a high enough tag score to propose synonyms yet.

@RaghavSood: Done. ;)

Makes sense to me.
I'm assuming that merging them will result in old mastercoin tags simply being replaced by omni tags? 
Would searching for mastercoin on the site redirect users to the omni tag, post-merge?. 
Doing a quick search on the site, mastercoin returns 61 results, while omni returns 16 results, for whatever thats worth. 

I believe that's how it works. The recent zmq->zeromq merge resulted in zmq redirecting

When we merge one tag into another, we have the option to keep a synonym or remove the old tag. In this case, I'd keep the synonym.
